# Can I minimize the number of objects used in this SBjson code?

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, sbjson

The response I receive from the server is formatted as such:

```
{
    "Data":{
        "Key": "Value"
        ...
    },
    "Key": "Value"
    ...
}
```

However, I am only interested in the elements under "Data".
Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [SBJsonParser new]; 
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
NSDictionary *responseData = [parser objectWithString:responseString];
NSString *infoString = [responseData objectForKey:@"Data"];
NSDictionary *infoData = [parser objectWithString:infoString];
```

Is there a way to perform the same thing without explicitly declaring 5 objects? Just looking for some sense of short-hand that I should be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last two lines are wrong - `"Data"` is actually an `NSDictionary`, so you don't need to double parse it.

Also, most objective-C programmers would nest calls where they know that the returns are safe - by which I mean don't need additional checking.  For instance, this would see a more natural implementation to me:

```
NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [[request responseString] JSONValue];
NSDictionary *infoData = [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"Data"];
```

Note that I am using the convenience method `JSONValue` from the category on NSObject that comes with `SBJSON`.